# PGP public key block Public-Key (old) - What does the OLD mean?

Tags: gnupg

System: Linux Mint 19.

---

Today I created a new GPG key pair using:

```
gpg --full-generate-key
```

I armor-exported the public key and have run:

```
file *.public
```

As a surprise I found my key or format or whatever to be *old*:

> PGP public key block Public-Key **(old)**

---

I used search engine a lot, but haven't managed to find out what exactly this means?

Comment: I think this question is more about the output of the ```file``` command. Have you tried asking on unix/Ubuntu stack exchanges? I was able to recreate this, not sure what it means though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OLD` likely means your PGP public key block uses old packet format. See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-4.2